# How do I synchronize GUI-Elements?

Tags: java, user-interface, observer-pattern

I have a little problem with my java-program. I wanna use Observer, to synchronize two GUIs.
But I can't synchronize the JComponent / JButton elements. For example:

I have a GUI-Class which implements the Observer-Class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements Observer
```

I have a second "GUI"-Class which extends the JButton-Class and makes changes on a specific Button-Element.

```
public class Karte extends JButton{
...
this.setEnabled(false);
...
```

How do I synchronize this Button via Observable? I have already tried to use "extends Observable" in this class, but the "setEnabled()" method is explicit for the JButton-Class, which is not Observable!

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: I first suggest not using `java.util.Observer` and `Observable`, and not extending classes unnecessarily. Use of model classes in Swing is very handy. Then just add listeners to models.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to let Karte *have* an Observable (rather than being one).

```
public class Karte extends JButton{

    final Observable obs = new Observable() {
        // override as needed here
    }

    // ...

    Observable asObservable() { return obs; }
}

myKarte.asObservable().addObserver(myGUI);
```

It's considered good practice to favor composition over inheritance, but sometimes it's simply necessary whether or not you want to!